PrimeVue InputNumber's width exceeds the width of its parent
I have a list of items in the cart that's presented in Bootstrap rows and cols. Each item has a PrimeVue InputNumber for changing the quantity of a specific product in the cart.
Here's a StackBlitz project with this issue.
This is how I use InputNumber:
<InputNumber v-model="item.qty"
             inputId="horizontal-buttons"
             showButtons
             buttonLayout="horizontal"
             :step="1"
             style="max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
<template #incrementbuttonicon>
  <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
    add
  </span>
</template>
<template #decrementbuttonicon>
  <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
    remove
  </span>
</template>
</InputNumber>

Here's the component with the list I've mentioned above:
<script setup>
import InputNumber from 'primevue/inputnumber'
import { useCartStore } from '../stores/cartStore.js'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const cartStore = useCartStore()
const { cart } = storeToRefs(cartStore)
const { deleteFromCart } = cartStore
</script>

<template>
  <div class="row mw-2000 mx-auto px-lg-5 px-0 my-0">
    <section class="col-9">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row border-top border-bottom cart-item"
             v-for="item in cart">
          <img class="col-2" :src="item.product.images[0]" alt="Product">
          <div class="col-6 d-inline-block overflow-ellipsis">
            {{ item.product.title }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 d-inline-block overflow-ellipsis">
            ${{ parseFloat(item.product.price).toFixed(2) }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <InputNumber v-model="item.qty"
                         inputId="horizontal-buttons"
                         showButtons
                         buttonLayout="horizontal"
                         :step="1" style="max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
              <template #incrementbuttonicon>
                <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                  add
                </span>
              </template>
              <template #decrementbuttonicon>
                <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                  remove
                </span>
              </template>
            </InputNumber>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger delete-product-btn d-inline-flex
                    justify-content-center align-items-center"
                    @click="deleteFromCart(item.product.id)">
              <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                close
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-3"></section>
  </div>
</template>

As you see, I tried applying style="max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" to the InputNumber component, but it didn't work. I also tried replacing max-width: 100% with width: 100%, but it also didn't work. Right now, the input looks like this:

I tried to inspect the component, but couldn't find any reason why it behaves like this. I haven't seen the InputNumber being set a fixed width or something similar anywhere.


To be clear, I want the InputNumber to fit its parent's width.
Thank you in advance!

The codesandbox is not publicly accessible. Otherwise, I recommend inspecting the whole HTML element in your browser devtools to see why it does not behave as you expect.

@kissu, I changed the link. If an error pops up, feel free to tell me. And here is the code of the cart page on GitHub. And I inspected the component. Couldn't find a single reason why it behaves like this. I haven't seen the InputNumber being set a fixed width or anything similar anywhere.

The sandbox you provided does not work. Without a working one, it's unlikely you'll get help with CSS. We need a way to inspect the resulting HTML result of your code. From a  quick peek, I noticed you're mixing bootstrap with primevue. That's not a good idea, unless you really know what you're doing and hand-picking elements of each which do not conflict.

Sorry, question closed. I apologise for being useless.

Huh ? What do you mean?

@kissu, I mean that I shouldn't have asked this. I also shouldn't have used Bootstrap and PrimeVue together. Going to fix this. Thank you for paying attention! Bye!

All good, this platform is to ask technical questions so that you can improve. Don't beat yourself or anything. It is true that you should skip using Bootstrap with Vue3 altogether, but it's not the end of the world if you did, just move forward. You did a great job at explaining your issue properly + put some effort into it, I found it quite nice for a new member here. :)

@kissu, thank you for appreciating my efforts! I really considered deleting my account, so I "won't ask something useless again". I've never had a good relationship with StackOverflow.

@kissu, your comments opened my eyes on a fundamental issue with my project. I did the wrong thing using PrimeVue and Bootstrap together. But I struggle to make a decision on choosing one of them. I absolutely love PrimeVue components. With them, I managed to make a multi-range price slider that works flawlessly without too much effort. I also use a carousel from that kit. But I have a Bootstrap layout, and changing it to a PrimeFlex one looks like a big task, considering the fact I'm not familiar with PrimeFlex yet. I guess I'm gonna use Bootstrap.

@tao, I decided I'm gonna stick to Bootstrap. Unfortunately, I can't make the sandbox work. When I log in and start working on it, it launches fine. But when I use the public link, I get that @vnode-... error. I tried deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, and running npm install before sharing, but that didn't do the trick. I coudn't find another way to solve this issue, unfortunately. You can ignore this question, it turned out that I have an issue with choosing the tech stack.

Would be curious to know why no good relationship with SO, writing an article about it currently. If you use Bootstrap only for the layout, I recommend ditching it and using Flexbox or Grid, you will have an easier time and get some good foundations in CSS. You could even maybe try to ditch PrimeVue if you want to fully improve and learn the internals of each component you're using. If you struggle to make a [repro], you can always share a public Github link repo.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Although you were not able to provide a runnable example (which is pretty much mandatory for CSS questions), your question was not useless (for example, I noticed you're using bootstrap with primevue). If you still need the question answered, consider providing a simpler [mcve] (only rendering a NumberInput in a  container) and we'll be able to tell you why it doesn't expand/shrink to meet the expectations.

@tao, can I host this on GitHub Pages? Will that be enough? To make it clearer, I decided not to use Bootstrap anymore, and replace it with Tailwind. But I might need to know why the input might behave this way.

I recommend hosting it on Netlify rather, Github pages is not that great tbh.

@tao, I deployed the project on Netlify. Here it is. Add some products to the cart first.

The link you provided doesn't work (because you haven't set up routing properly on Netlify, but that's a separate issue, irrelevant here). I was able to access the app by removing /products from the link. How do I get to the page you displayed in the question? I couldn't find it using the app's menu.

@tao, choose a category and a subcategory of a product in the "Product" dropdown in the nav. Like this. You can choose any item from the menu, they all link to the same page.

@tao, I deeply apologize for the inconvenience, I'm brand new to Netlify.

No need for apologies. For me, the 8 clicks sequence you perform in the demo wasn't obvious from the link you presented above. I probably would have understood how to get there if the link ended in /cart.

@tao, as I see, you got there, right? My bad, I didn't record the address bar. Sorry for that.

It looks like the issue is fixed by applying 1, 2:
.p-inputnumber input {
  width: 100%;
}

but I'm not sure I understand the DOM mechanics behind it.
My best guess is that the width is silently imposed by the user agent (the browser) which, according to the HTML standard, "should ensure that at least 20 characters are visible". This is confirmed by the input shrinking when given a size attribute value smaller than 20 (default value).
I inspected all CSS applied to span.p-inputnumber, its inner input, its inner buttons and the input's inner shadow DOM and nothing else explains why they would exceed the parent width.
Also, the behavior does not seem to be caused by conflicting CSS rules between primevue and bootstrap. (Not saying using them together is advisable, but I seriously doubt it is the underlying cause of the unwanted CSS behavior).

1 - if you want this behavior only on some inputs, apply the fix selectively, using a dedicated class.
2 - giving the input a CSS overflow value of auto, hidden, overlay or scroll seems to have the same effect as the proposed fix (only tested in Chrome).
3 - If I were you, I'd open an issue on primevue's repo letting them know about the behavior, it's likely something they want to fix. Most developers would expect the input not to exceed the parent width out of the box, without having to apply any CSS.

Thank you! I don't know why I forgot about the size attribute and its default value. All your fixes work like a charm. I wish I could give your answer a million upvotes. As for PrimeVue, I'll open an issue on its GitHub repo.

Simply use the fluid attribute on the InputNumber component:
https://primevue.org/fluid/
